# Why do tabulate or summarize not take into account missing values when implemented inside a program?

Tags: syntax, stata, missing-data

As an illustrative example, suppose this is your dataset:

```
cat sex age
1   1   13
1   0   14
1   1   .
2   1   23
2   1   45
2   1   15
```

If you want to create a table of frequencies between `cat` and `sex`, you `tabulate` these two variables and you get the following result:

```
tab cat sex
       |         sex
   cat |         0          1 |     Total
-----------+----------------------+----------
     1 |         1          2 |         3 
     2 |         0          3 |         3 
-----------+----------------------+----------
 Total |         1          5 |         6
```

I am writing a Stata program where the three variables are involved, i.e. `cat`, `sex` and `age`. Getting the matrix of frequencies for the first two variables is just an intermediate step that I need for further computation.

```
cap program drop myexample
program def myexample, rclass byable(recall) sortpreserve
version 14
syntax varlist [aweight iweight fweight] [if] [in] [ , AGgregate  ]
args var1 var2 var3
tempname F

marksample touse 
set more off

if "`aggregate'" == "" {
    local var1:  word 1 of `varlist'
    local var2: word 2 of `varlist'
    local var3:  word 3 of `varlist'

    qui: tab `var1' `var2' [`weight' `exp'] if `touse', matcell(`F')  label matcol(`var2')

    mat list `F'
}
   end
```

However, when I run:

```
myexample cat sex age
```

I get this result which is not what I expected:

```
__000001[2,2]
     c1  c2
r1   1   1
r2   0   3
```

That is, given that `age` contains a missing value, even if it is not directly involved in the tabulation, the program ignores the missing value and does not take into account that observation. I need to get the result of the first tabulation. I have tried using `summarize` instead, but the same problem arises. When implemented inside the program, missing values are not counted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by `marksample`. Rule 5 in `help mark` states

> The marker variable is set to 0 in observations for which any of the
>   numeric variables in varlist contain a numeric missing value.

You should use the novarlist option. According to the help file,

> novarlist is for use with marksample.  It specifies that missing values
>      among variables in varlist not cause the marker variable to be set to 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not realize that missing values were also marked with zero. Now it works.

Answer (score 3):

You are complaining about behaviour which you built into your own program. The responsibility and the explanation are in your hands.

The effect of

```
marksample touse
```

followed by calling up a command with the qualifier

```
if `touse'
```

is to ignore missing values. `marksample` by default marks as "to use" those observations in which all variables specified have non-missing values; the other observations are marked as to be ignored. It also takes account of any `if` or `in` qualifiers and any zero weights.

It's also true, as @Noobie explains, that omitting missing values from a tabulation is default for `tabulate` in any case.

So, to get the result you want you'd need to modify your `marksample` call to

```
marksample touse, novarlist
```

and to call up `tabulate` with the `missing` option (if it's compulsory) or to allow users to specify a `missing` option which you then pass to `tabulate`.

You also ask about `summarize`. By design that command ignores missing values. I don't know what you would expect `summarize` to do about them. It could report a count of missing values. If you want that, several other commands will oblige, such as `codebook` or `missings` (*Stata Journal*). You can always include a report on missings in your program, such as using `count` to count the missings and `display` the result.

I understand your program to be very much work in progress, so won't comment on details you don't ask about.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nick! Indeed, I did not explain myself properly given that I omitted what I tried with summarize. I was applying it to "sex" (which does not have missing values) to get r(N). But, the problem again was that observation three had already been deleted. Specifying novarlist was the key point.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand well you want tab to include missing values? If so, you just have to ask for it

```
tab myvar1 myvar2, mi
```

from the documentation

> **missing**  :            treat missing values like other values

Comment: Thanks Nobbie! My question was related with the sample itself and not with missing values as a category.